problem with class exam and qformat when I use enumerate
I have a problem with this code :
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\qformat{\textbf{Exercice \thequestion~:}\hfill}
\begin{questions}
\question 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{questions}
\end{document}

The 1 of item 1 appear in the same line than Exercice. How can I handle this ?

Add \mbox{} after \question, I'd say.

It works, thank you

Note that exam class uses lists for questions, subquestions, etc. where each environment is assgned to a specific level, whereas normal lists (like enumerate) simply add a new level each time.  This can cause problems if you intermix the two.
